# HOC Redux Dispatch gets called after child component calls React componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state, amazon-cognito

I have a higher order component(HOC) which is used for authorizing and refreshing the user sessions.

This is the RequireAuth HOC and it's componentWillMount

```
componentWillMount() {
  console.log('HOC componentWillMount');
   // checks with authorizer that token is valid if not refresh token
    getUserFromLocalStorage()
      // update redux with new refresh token
      .then(data => {
        console.log('getUserFromLocalStorage')
        this.props.setUserToReduxState(data);
        console.log(
          'user sucess retrieved and user setUserToReduxState: ',
          data
        );
      })
      .catch(() => {
        logoutUserFromReduxState();
      });
  }
}
```

This is my route call

```
<Route exact path="/devices" component={RequireAuth(Devices)} />
```

and here is my componentDidMount for the Devices component

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('componentDidMount')
  // calls api
  this.loadData();
}
```

This child component calls the API which requires a token.
However when the token get's refreshed, it refreshes before the API get's called in the devices component but the redux action that get's returns from the '.then' promise in the HOC doesn't update the redux state before the api call in the child component.

Is there a way to make sure the token has been update/redux state before the child tries to call the API?

Comment: show a loading spinner or something while token is being fetched instead of mounting the child component right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can add a condition inside your HOC not to render your "enhanced component"  - in your case Devices until the setUserToReduxState is resolved with the user's token. only after the user's token is set your Devices component will render the loadDate method will be triggered.

e.g. - you can map the state of your user to a variable. If the user does not exist - do not render the component you pass to your HOC.

EDIT: (added code snippet)

```
// In your render method get the current user from redux - see  mapStateToProps functoion
render(){
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
        return (
        <div>
            {
              user && user.token
              ? <Component {...this.props} />
              : null // Here you can replace this with spinner if you want..
            }
        </div>
      )
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.auth.user
})
```

Now when the user is set your component will re-render and the Devices component will trigger the loadData method when the token is set for sure.

Comment: This is a good answer. You could make it a great answer by including some example code based on the OPs code

Comment: @tsahnar thanks for that. Are you able to prove an example by anychance? Thanks

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense. Once authenticated they have a token that refreshes every hour and the code changes. Is there a way to make sure that the new refreshed token used for the API call? At the moment if the token refreshes, redux will not update the state before  componentDidMount fires in the child component. Cheers @tsahnar